# Corners of polygons resting on a sphere

Tags: general-topology, plane-geometry

Assume a set of evenly distributed points on a sphere.  Each point is contained in a plane normal to the sphere.  The planes will intersect each other forming convex polygons centered on the points.

How do I find the corner points of the polygons?

I can generate a set of points that are roughly evenly distributed on a sphere.  Using POV-Ray, I can generate a larger sphere, then 'cut-away' the planes that are normal to those points.  I am left with a 3D shape made of convex polygons.  Such a shape can be seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZCic.jpg

I want to know the corner points of the polygons so I can create a 2D drawing of each polygon; which will then be used to carve plywood "faces", to build a large version of the shape.

Each corner point resides at the intersections of three adjoining polygons; and the polygons are contained in planes that are normal to the sphere.  So it seems likely I need to determine the formulas for all the planes, then calculate the intersections, three planes at a time, to find the corners of the polygons.

How do I find the intersections of three planes, given that I know a point in each plane, and that the planes are normal to a sphere, and the points are on the surface the sphere?

The explanation at vi tutor -- http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/space/three_planes.html -- probably explains it, but I can't follow the explanation.  Also the Wikipedia article on Plane_(geometry) probably explains some of what I need, but I can't follow its explanations either.

Assuming the intersection of three planes will give me the corner points, this generates the separate question of determining which points are "neighbors" (their polygons share a border); otherwise I will generate a vast number intersections -- only a few of which are of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the planes normal to the sphere at two (non-antipodal) points intersect on a line that projects to the great circle equidistant between those two points.  So what you need is a Voronoi diagram on the sphere: the corner points correspond to the intersections of three planes corresponding to Voronoi regions with a common vertex.

Comment: I'm not sure if  a Voronoi diagram is what I'm looking for.  The polygon corner points are not on the sphere, but somewhere above it; though I imagine each Voronoi corner point is probably on the line from the origin through the polygon's corner point.  Of course, this begs the question, as I don't know how to generate a Voronoi diagram on a sphere.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The Voronoi diagram on the sphere tells you which planes to intersect to get the corner.  Googling "Voronoi diagram sphere" gives lots of hits.

Comment: Thank you, I will search for "Voronoi diagram sphere"